# Access FileSaver from pyimagej

Tags: python, imagej, pyimagej

How can one access FileSaver from pyimagej?

Everything that I see online is something like this:

```py
from ij.io import FileSaver
```

But with pyimagej we are loading it differently:

```py
import imagej
ij = imagej.init()
```

Also `ij.io()`.FileSaver does not exists

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to save an image to disk, use this:

```py
ij.io().save(myImage, filePath)
```

Where `myImage` is the image to save, and `filePath` is where to save it. The output image format will be inferred from the file extension.

If your goal is specifically to use `ij.io.FileSaver`, you can do so as follows:

```py
import imagej
from scyjava import jimport
ij = imagej.init(...) # replace '...' with desired parameters here
FileSaver = jimport('ij.io.FileSaver')
imp = ... # get or make an ImagePlus somehow
fs = FileSaver(imp)
```